# Remove install dialog from ubuntu usb stick

Tags: live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bypass “Try it / Install” screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

I've created a ubuntu booting usb stick. Is it possible to remove the "install ubuntu" dialog that appears everytime I boot from the usb stick?

Comment: See answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by first formatting the USB and then install the ISO image to a CD.

Next plug both USB and CD in and reboot. When you reboot to the CD select install but install it to your USB drive and for the bootloader select your USB drive unless you want problems.